# getStringSet() throws an exception - SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store a set of values and then get them back with SharedPreferences but when I'm trying to get the set, I get this error:

```
"java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Set"
```

This is how I put it:

```
private val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
     fun setStringSet(key: String, value: Set<String>?) {
        editor.putStringSet(key, value)
        editor.apply()
    }
```

This is how I'm trying to get the information:

```
fun getStringSet(key: String, defaultValue: Set<String>?): Set<String>? {
    return sharedPref.getStringSet(key, defaultValue)
}
```

Comment: What is the `value` that you are passing? It needs to be a `Set<String>`, not a `String`. Also, you need to call `apply()` on the Editor that you put the String in. You are currently putting the String in one Editor, throwing that Editor away to the garbage collector, creating a new Editor, and calling `apply()` on the new empty Editor, so nothing will happen.

Comment: Just updated the question. I'm passing Set<String>. Also moved the "apply()", but still same issue is happening.

Comment: This can happen if you *previously* saved a `String` to the `SharedPreferences` identified by this same key, and that value is still there when you try to read it back as a `Set<String>`. You can use Device File Explorer in Android Studio to look at the XML where your `SharedPreferences` are saved and see what's in there.

Comment: I just store Set<String>, not String. this is the XML file I'm seeing:

Comment: <string name="requested_permissions">VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgcHJlZml4IGZvciBhIGxpc3QurO0ABXNyABNqYXZhLnV0aWwuQXJyYXlMaXN0eIHSHZnHYZ0DAAFJAARzaXpleHAAAAABdwQAAAAB&#10;dAAnYW5kcm9pZC5wZXJtaXNzaW9uLkFDQ0VTU19GSU5FX0xPQ0FUSU9OeA==&#10;    </string>

Comment: no strings! it's just the set<String> that I added

Comment: Test with a different key, you probably saved a string and try to retrieve a Set from an already used key.